# How to filter dates before or equal a selected value in a segment w/o using date slicer in PowerBI

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I have a visual in PowerBI showing values by quarter and I want to show only the quarter that are before or equal to the selected date in a segment, how to do that ?

When I use the segment the interaction on the other visuals filter only on the equal selection. I want the dates filtered before or equal the selection. I don't want to use the date silder because I want the selection to be only by quarter and not on a specific date.

Below is a screenshot of what I'm looking for :

(i) it shows the current behavior based on the selection

(ii) it shows what I would like to do

[see what I expected to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7nLt.png)

This is my model (I have two data tables related to one date table)

[see my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idgr0.png)

I tried this query but it doesn't work

```
Total Numbers =
CALCULATE(
    SUM('T_Data_1'[Numbers]),
    FILTER(
        T_Data_1,
        T_Data_1[Date] <= MAX(T_Dates[TrimestreDate])
    )
)
```

I also tried Dynamic Parameter M but I'm not using Direct Query so I wasn't able to bind the paramater and my report will be published on PowerBI Report Server that doesn't support the feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone found the solution from another forum so I share it here:

It requires to create an additional date table independant from the others. I created this independant table based on the first date table so I have the same threashold:

```
T_Dates_Ind = GENERATE (
        DISTINCT(T_Dates[TrimestreDate]),
        VAR trimestreDate = [TrimestreDate]
        VAR year =
            YEAR ( trimestreDate )
        VAR quarterMiddle = 
            CONCATENATE("Trim ",QUARTER(trimestreDate))
        RETURN
            ROW ( 
            "Année, Trim", year & " " & quarterMiddle
    ))
```

I keep it with no relation and then I can get the selected date to use it as value to filter the measure:

```
Total Numbers To Selected Quarter = 
VAR _max = MAXX(ALLSELECTED(T_Dates_Ind),T_Dates_Ind[TrimestreDate])
VAR _min = DATE(YEAR(_max)-1,MONTH(_max),DAY(_max))
RETURN
CALCULATE(SUM(T_Data_1[Numbers]), FILTER(T_Dates, T_Dates[Date] <= _max && T_Dates[Date] >= _min))
```

Link to the video the guy shared: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44fGGmg9fHI

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
Total Numbers =
CALCULATE(
    SUM('T_Data_1'[Numbers]),
    FILTER(
        ALL([T_Data_1[Date]),
        T_Data_1[Date] <= MAX(T_Dates[TrimestreDate])
    )
)
```